# Fortran - Module Subroutine Argument Intent Confusion- INOUT vs OUT

Tags: module, scope, fortran, subroutine

Lets say there is a vector:

```
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(maxn) ::  rho
```

which is allocated values in an initial subroutine (along with `dp` and `maxn`) and is called from the main program.

The main program then calls a module which contains a (different) subroutine to evolve `rho`. The subroutine argument for `rho` is defined as:

```
SUBROUTINE sum_density(a, b, c, ....., rho)
```

In this subroutine rho is declared as:

```
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(maxn), INTENT(OUT)  ::  rho
```

Yet the code contains the following line, prior to any values being associated with `rho`:

```
foo1= foo2*foo3(i)/rho(i)
```

I would have thought that the module subroutine would not have had access to the `rho` defined in the main program. I expected the compiler to complain and require the intent to be changed to `(INOUT)` or say something like `rho` is undefined. Even if I do change it to `(INOUT)` there is no difference in the results. The module subroutine must be accessing the value of `rho` in the main program and using it even though the intent is declared as `OUT`.

My question is - In this scenario what is the difference between using in `INTENT(OUT)` and the `INTENT(INOUT)`?

Comment: Did you really mean `INTENT(IN)` in your last sentence?

Comment: Oops, thank you for pointing that out - FIXED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `INTENT(OUT)` the program is not standard conforming, because it accesses the array which has an undefined value.

However, the software implementation is likely to work, because of the way explicit shape arrays are usually implemented - by passing the address of the array. If the array you passed was non-contiguous, let's say

```
  rho(::2)
```

the compiler is likely to create a copy, which is passed and you are likely to encounter a problem, because the array may contain garbage with `intent(out)`.

Regarding the warning, they are not obligatory but compilers do warn about this if you use flags such as `-warn` or `-Wall`.

For `intent(in)` the difference comes out when you try to modify `rho`. If you try that the compiler has to issue an error.

**About the scope:**

It is not really correct to talk about the scope here, the original `rho` is definitely not in the scope of the subroutine, only the dummy argument is. The re-use of the same name is perhaps confusing. Imagine they are actually called `rho1` in the program and `rho2` in the subroutine. Then it is clear that `rho1` is not in the scope of the subroutine, but `rho2` is.

Now, `rho2` is not guaranteed to have the same value as `rho1` at the start of the subroutine with `intent(out)`, but it is guaranteed to have it with `intent(inout)`. The reason is that the argument passing may be implemented using copy-in and copy-out and the copy-in can be omitted for `intent(out)`.

Consider this code:

```
module m
contains
  subroutine sub(a2)
    real, intent(out) :: a2(4)
    print *,a2
    a2 = 2
  end subroutine
end

  use m

  real :: a1(8)

  a1 = 1

  call sub(a1(::2))

end
```

With some compiler it prints 4 times one, as one might expect, but with others or with some compiler parameters it prints garbage:

```
sunf90 intent2.f90 
./a.out 
 5.879759E-39 0.0E+0 0.0E+0 0.0E+0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and for pointing out my typo in the last sentence of the question). So could you please clarify if the originally declared rho is normally out of scope of the module if the INTENT is declared as OUT? Are you saying that it is brought into scope due to the way in which explicit shape arrays are implemented?

Comment: The originally declared `rho` is _never_ in scope in the module procedure, no matter what the `intent` is. The memory associated with it however is also associated with the dummy argument in the module procedure.